# "We only collect anonymized data". Roughly what are the limits of this?

Tags: united-states, privacy, california, data, anonymization

Say a program that Bob is using asks to collect "anonymized data". Bob agrees. But roughly at what point is "anonymized" a false statement?

If I have Bob's shopping habits, gendre, device make, ip address/general location area, etc.; at some point, it's more than enough to uniquely identify Bob. In fact, I remember coming across plenty of academic literature about the subject back in 2015 ([relevant wiki link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_re-identification))

My question is: are there definitive rulings/laws on the matter? It's definitely a gray area, but I'd like to know any concrete law/legislation surrounding it. Especially in the jurisdiction of the USA, and California in particular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are referring to online data collection, "personal information" is defined in California in [Cal. Civ 1798.140](https://leginfo.legislature.ca.gov/faces/codes_displayText.xhtml?division=3.&part=4.&lawCode=CIV&title=1.81.5) as

> information that identifies, relates to,
> describes, is reasonably capable of being associated with, or could
> reasonably be linked, directly or indirectly, with a particular
> consumer or household. Personal information includes, but is not
> limited to, the following if it identifies, relates to, describes, is
> reasonably capable of being associated with, or could be reasonably
> linked, directly or indirectly, with a particular consumer or
> household:
>
> (A) Identifiers such as a real name, alias, postal address, unique
> personal identifier, online identifier, Internet Protocol address,
> email address, account name, social security number, driver’s license
> number, passport number, or other similar identifiers.
>
> (B) Any personal information described in subdivision (e) of Section
> 1798.80.
>
> (C) Characteristics of protected classifications under California or
> federal law.
>
> (D) Commercial information, including records of personal property,
> products or services purchased, obtained, or considered, or other
> purchasing or consuming histories or tendencies.
>
> (E) Biometric information.
>
> (F) Internet or other electronic network activity information,
> including, but not limited to, browsing history, search history, and
> information regarding a consumer’s interaction with an internet
> website application, or advertisement.
>
> (G) Geolocation data.
>
> (H) Audio, electronic, visual, thermal, olfactory, or similar
> information.
>
> (I) Professional or employment-related information.
>
> (J) Education information, defined as information that is not publicly
> available personally identifiable information as defined in the Family
> Educational Rights and Privacy Act (20 U.S.C. Sec. 1232g; 34 C.F.R.
> Part 99).
>
> (K) Inferences drawn from any of the information identified in this
> subdivision to create a profile about a consumer reflecting the
> consumer’s preferences, characteristics, psychological trends,
> predispositions, behavior, attitudes, intelligence, abilities, and
> aptitudes.
>
> (L) Sensitive personal information.

But also, it "does not include consumer information that is deidentified or aggregate consumer information". To answer the next question,

> “Deidentified” means information that cannot reasonably be used to
> infer information about, or otherwise be linked to, a particular
> consumer provided that the business that possesses the information:
>
> (1) Takes reasonable measures to ensure that the information cannot be
> associated with a consumer or household.
>
> (2) Publicly commits to maintain and use the information in
> deidentified form and not to attempt to reidentify the information,
> except that the business may attempt to reidentify the information
> solely for the purpose of determining whether its deidentification
> processes satisfy the requirements of this subdivision.
>
> (3) Contractually obligates any recipients of the information to
> comply with all provisions of this subdivision.

The conspicuous lack of "and" or "or" in these clauses raises a red flag, in case the AG deems that all three conditions must be met to qualify as "deidentified"